# Generics Issues while implementing monad

Tags: scala, monads

I saw the below code on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242295/scala-monad-or-function-composition). But the problem it has is that it's `map` and `flatMap` definitions aren't fully correct. `map` must be able to transform the inside value of a monadic container/context, and the same way a `flatMap` should take a value, transform it and put it back in the monadic context/container. In the example below it's taking an `A` and giving an `A` or `M[A]` (instead of `A->B` or `A->M[B]`)

```
trait Mine[A] {
  def get(): A
  def map(f: A => A): Mine[A]
  def flatMap(f: A => Mine[A]): Mine[A]
}

case class Attempt1[A, B](a: (A, B)) extends Mine[(A, B)] {
  def get(): (A, B) = a
  def map(f: ((A, B)) => (A, B)): Mine[(A, B)] = {
   Attempt1(f(a._1, a._2))
  }
  def flatMap(f: ((A, B)) => Mine[(A, B)]): Mine[(A, B)] = {
   f(a._1, a._2)
  }
}
```

So I thought of changing it and that's where I got stuck. The below code is failing for all the right reasons but can someone guide on how to implement something similar?

```
trait Opt[A] {
 def map[B](f: A => B): Opt[B]
 def flatMap[B](f: A => Opt[B]): Opt[B]
}

case class Osome[A, B](a: (A, B)) extends Opt[(A, B)] {
 def flatMap[C, D](f: ((A, B)) => Opt[(C,D)]): Opt[(C, D)] = {
  f(a._1, a._2)
 }
 def map [C, D] (f: ((A, B)) => (C, D)): Opt[(C, D)] = {
  Osome(f(a._1, a._2))
 }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make an arbitrary class in Scala as a monad instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673717/make-an-arbitrary-class-in-scala-as-a-monad-instance)

Comment: At the face it seems similar, but I think this one is more related to generics as I am not able to make this work for `[(A, B)] -> [(C, D)]`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you don't implement the `map` and `flatMap` methods of `Opt` in your `Osome` class, but you overload them. In your trait they both have one type parameter, but in your implementation they have two. Aside from that, your `Osome` would anyway not be a monad, as it restricts the resulting type of `map` and `flatMap`, where monads allow for arbitrary types.

Comment: Thank you for answering and it makes sense. I have a question if you may help. Scala has `Option` class with `flatMap` and `Map` defined as final methods, but I see that `Some` which inherits from `Option` also has the same methods with the same signature; how is that possible (I don't think `Option` has `flatMap` and `Map` as `private def`

Comment: Also, since many people implement `Monad` as `trait` and then extend it, is there a way to extend a `trait` with `map` as `def map[B] (f: A=>B):M[B]` to something `def map(f: ((A, B)) => (C, D)): M[(C, D)]`. Just like it's in the first example in my question (which btw works perfectly)